# Reloading page with header does not work if protecting php files

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Trying to protect direct access to php files in htaccess with:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.+?\ [^?]+\.php[?\ ]
RewriteRule \.php$ - [F]
```

Everything works fine, except for pages using refresh/reload via header:

```
header("Location: $exampleurl");
```

Is anyone able to help? Thx in advance.

PS: bonus question: is there as well some rule for blocking massive access (too many requests aka DDOS) from proxy via HTTP?

Comment: Please clarify what happens in both cases you're describing.

Comment: Luis: if i use the htaccess code above i get (550 Access Denied) for any page using php header() redirect [redirecting from within the page]. It looks as some sort of cross-domain or cross-reference problem or something like that.

Comment: And what is the location they should redirect to?

Comment: from: `header("Location: $exampleurl.php?id=123");` to: `header("Location: $exampleurl.php?id=321");` - need it that way cause i need to capture some values, that's why it can't be just plain a href link. and that page use this as rewrite rule: `#RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/page/(.+)$ $1/$2/page/ [R,L]
#RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/page/$ page.php?ab=$1&ac=$2 [L]`

Comment: You protect direct access to PHP files, so you can't redirect to them.

Comment: nope the code above (htaccess) is to prevent someone accessing directly for example: `example.com/page.php`, or `example.com/list.php`. It works as a charm, but if page use inside code with `header();` it dosen't work and gives you the 500 access denied code.

Comment: Try putting Header('Location: google.com'); in the page and check whether you'll get the 500 access denied code

Comment: and how this gonna help if re-directed to google? google.com obviously doesn't use my htaccess file with rewriterules protecting php files.

Comment: That's what I'm telling you. The problem is not the redirection. The problem is you're redirecting to .php files which you protect in your .htaccess.

Comment: so explain me this: if i use a href url pointing to some page (SEF rewrite rule applied = nicer url) it works, but if same url is passed via header() in php code it doesn't work. Both using example.com/page/123/

Comment: Is the header() using the full URL or a path-relative one? That's very strange, though.

Comment: I just figured out what the problem is: `header();` is not the problem. Problem is you can't use `[PHP_SELF]` in the passing form, but the full path of the page you are calling this form from. I think `[PHP_SELF]` is using `example.com/page.php?ab=123`, but i was trying to pass `example.com/page/123/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the path shown in the browser in PHP to pass it onto your redirect, use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` or `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']`

Comment: I am ok with passing nice SEF url, instead of path with query string. thx

Comment: do you know how to exclude specific php file from this ruleset? I need to exclude all cron job php files, so they are not blocked by this rule of (deny direct access to php files) - `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.+?\ [^?]+\.php[?\ ]
RewriteRule \.php$ - [F]`

Comment: Please open a new question if this is not your original one.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out what the problem is: `header();` is not the problem. Problem is you can't use `[PHP_SELF]` in the passing form, but the full path of the page you are calling this form from. I think `[PHP_SELF]` is using `example.com/page.php?ab=123`, but i was trying to pass `example.com/page/123/`.

Comment: You got there. `[PHP_SELF]` will pass the path your accessing, which is  `example.com/page.php?ab=123`, although your browser shows `example.com/page/123/`

Comment: Check my answer for an alternate way to `[PHP_SELF]` which will work :)

Comment: @Luis is there some rewrite rule for blocking massive HTTP requests to the same URL?

Comment: No, a DDoS attack is not that easy to stop. You'd be good using CloudFlare